# Measures to avoid locations with bad air quality and inversion for asthmatics?

Tags: health, planning, tips-and-tricks, traffic

Bergen, Norway, is an example of a city surrounded by mountains where the air quality can get very bad, terrible for asthmatics. This phenomenon is called [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(meteorology)). Before the symptoms begin, the asthmatic person may alleviate the symptoms by measures such as traveling to locations with inversion during summer and observing bad geographic landscapes so avoiding them altogether such as strong winds blowing directly to valleys with clouds very low, hardly seeing sun. Instead of asking directly list-style question *"What are cities in the world that asthmatics should avoid due to poor air quality?"*:

**What are the measures an asthmatic traveller can make to choose new travelling locations not affected by inversion?**

Comment: Are you talking for living (expats forum) or for visiting?  If the later then when, as the time of year often plays a role in the air quality.

Comment: There is a list of world's most polluted list of cities. That is a place to start from. And winter exacerbates pollution.

Comment: The particular effect you've mentioned is caused an [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(meteorology). I've linked to the Wikipedia article. I thought Denver also had issues (but it's not on the list.

Comment: Beijing,  Mexico City, and New Delhi

Comment: [The problem in Bergen seems to be caused by wood stoves, not cars.](http://www.theguardian.com/cities/2016/jan/19/log-fires-traffic-fumes-cause-bergen-air-pollution) "Recently, the Norwegian Institute for Air Research (NILU) published statistics showing that “particulate matter from log burning in cities is more dangerous than pollution from traffic”. Research by Statistics Norway (SSB), meanwhile, concluded that 61% of the particulate matter in Norway’s air stems from its 1.7 million existing log fires, compared to 39% from private vehicles, buses and lorries."

Comment: Wood stoves should be banned. Yesterday I inhaled a big dose of poisonous air when returning home after running outside. The neighbors had turned on their wood stove :( .

Comment: Looks like a hopless situation there: “In Bergen, it is hard to ban heating by logs because of other health-related worries, including people freezing. We have many poorly insulated, old timber houses where log fires are a major heat source. But we are working on this. If a ban is considered, the city council will have to agree on a new regulation and we are not there yet.”

Comment: @mkennedy Denver is not surrounded by mountains. They're only on one side (west).

Comment: @phoog Yes, west, where most air pressure systems come from in the area. If fresh air can't get over the range--an inversion can certainly happen. Otherwise, why would LA be on the list? It only has mountains to the east.

Comment: @mkennedy LA is more complicated. The northern part is in the San Fernando Valley, surrounded by mountains, and the central part is in the LA Basin, with mountains to the NW, N, and NE. The LA basin as a whole has mountains on all sides but the SW (facing the ocean). Also, in my limited experience, Denver is much windier than LA, especially at the edge of the front range. But I've never been there in the summer, and an image search for "Denver smog" yields some pretty impressive pictures, so maybe it should be on the list.

Comment: Avoid France, there is no regulation at all about wood burning. Anyone can burn his trash in his woodstove without any risk (villages are the worst). And avoid especially the French Alpes, the air pollution is literally deadly (you won’t hear about it because these info would greatly damage the French tourism revenues. Some French have been threatened on their own life to talk about it in the Alpes, because of that. One of these guys was a doctor.)

Comment: @GuillaumeCombot : any references to both assertion ('Anyone can burn his trash in his woodstove' and 'Some French have been threatened on their own life to talk about it') ?

Comment: @audionuma  ● concerning the trash burning, there is no regulation about it (so  absolutly no control). By the way, log bruning are not better, since they contain 150 more PAH (carcinogen particules) smoke from diesel exhaust vehicule. http://particleandfibretoxicology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1743-8977-3-1

Comment: @audionuma ● concerning the guy who was threatened, I was mistaken, “only” his carrer was threatened. This doctor Frédéric Champly  talked about air pollution in a the Alps Valley and was threatened by several politcians and (according to the second link bellow) some ban supporters have been assaulted. Many people on the vally relie on tourism revenue (in partcicular sport) and information about the air pollution threaten their revenues.
http://www.ledauphine.com/haute-savoie/2015/02/19/pollution-le-maire-demande-des-sanctions-contre-un-medcein-urgentiste
http://acpassy.free.fr/

Comment: NRK article about Kindergradens with warnings about air quality [here](https://www.nrk.no/vestland/barnehage-vil-halda-255-barn-inne-i-frykt-for-luftforureining-i-bergen-1.14772252) in Bergen

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend looking at [this live and historical dataset of air quality, mapped out globally](http://berkeleyearth.org/air-pollution-overview/). Values over 100 indicate the air quality could be problematic for sensitive groups, such as asthmatics. . It's important to note that air quality varies a lot based on time of year, weather, etc. so look at the values for the same dates as you plan to travel will give you a good idea of what cities to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

### The Air Quality Index

There are several air quality monitoring websites out there. These use an [Air Quality Index (AQI)](https://www.airnow.gov/index.cfm?action=aqibasics.aqi) ranging from 0 to 500, where a 0 indicates good air quality, and 500 indicates hazardously unhealthy air, as detailed in the table below:

> [image: Air Quality Index colours explained]

### Worldwide Air Quality Monitors

[The World Air Quality Index Team runs an online real-time world map of air quality.](http://aqicn.org/map/world/) They are a China-based organisation which collaborates with Chinese, American, and worldwide Environment Protection Agencies to gather and publish air quality data.

Another tool is provided by [CITEAIR who runs a website showing a comparison on air quality in European cities](http://www.airqualitynow.eu/comparing_home.php).

[The World Health Organisation maintains an Global Urban Ambient Air Pollution Database](http://www.who.int/phe/health_topics/outdoorair/databases/cities/en/) whose summary data can be downloaded and analysed.

You could also look at [the data collected and published by the US Environment Protection Agency](https://www3.epa.gov/airdata/), which provides both raw and summary data. The EPA website also allows you to generate data plots for easier visualisation.